# Help drawing a very specific graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

> Draw an oriented graph with minimum number of vertices using 10 edges, 3 strongly connected components, every vertex having non-zero in and out degrees

I know it sounds like a homework question but i really want to understand how to create such a graph.
The answer is 5 vertices but i cannot get anything less than 7 vertices.
Can you help me find a way to draw the graph?
If you do i would appreciate also some tips on how to solve similar tasks.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Do you allow parallel edges or edges who are oriented in both directions simultaneously?  An answer of $5$ vertices and $10$ edges without parallel edges allowed would have implied that the non-oriented graph were $K_5$

Comment: yes it is allowed to use edges who are oriented in both directions simultaneously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want three components from five vertices, one of the components must consist of only one vertex; presumably the other two consist of two vertices each. Arrange the three components $A,B,C$ and add an edge from each vertex of $A$ to each vertex of $B$, same for $B$ to $C$ and for $A$ to $C$. This uses $|A||B|+|A||C|+|B||C|=2\cdot 2+2\cdot 1+2\cdot1=8$ edges. Within the 2-vertex components, add two-way edges, so that's $10$ edges in total. (If you count two-way edges as two one-ways, just drop two of the first eight edges in a harmless way).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $ 2 - 1 - 2 $.

In fact, 6 edges are enough, so throw more in to get 10.